# Como pasar una variable de un fichero php a un js

Tags: php, javascript

Hola tengo dos ficheros uno llamado funct.js y otro User.php en distintas rutas.

Me gustaría saber si puedo pasar una variable del User.php al funct.js en concreto estas.

[image: Variable fullname]

para después ser usada en el fichero funct.js.

Gracias

Comment: ¿Donde se "conocen" los 2 ficheros?

Comment: no se conocen esa es la cuestion que he de hacer que el javascript obtenga el dato de ese php.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a hacer una llamada de AJAX?

Comment: Bienvenido @AndrésNietoVelázquez, te recomiendo hagas el [tour] para que sepas un poco más de SOespañol, además de que ganarás tu primer medalla y también que pases a [ask] para que tus preguntas seas mejor recibidas y puedan ayudar a encontrar una solución.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo deseas enviar en el html unicamente tienes que asignarle la variable de esta manera

```
<?php 
$Valor = //Valor esperado que quieras mandar;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
//valor comun
var value = '<?php echo $valor;?>'
//Valor de array
var value = [<?php echo $valor;?>]
<script>
```

Si sabemos que PHP envia datos del servidor y javascript se ejecuta en el navegador tendriamos que ejecutar una funcion de en php es mandando el codigo para que el navegador lo ejecute

```
<script language= javascript type= text/javascript >
MiFuncionJS()
 {  alert (" EXITO")}
</script >

<?php
echo "<script>";
echo "MiFuncionJS();";
echo "</script>";
?>
```

De esta menera lo ejecutarias pero jamas lo habia intentado de manera muy especifica dentro de un archivo puro de php te recomiendo que intentes varias formas y esperemos que funcione